# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got (()

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-models

Hello i need ur help :)

Im at this Django project in school.
I replaced the auth_user table with the AbstractBaseUser Class and created a new class called UserLogin one.
So creating a superuser works fine, but creating the user with the signup page does not work

I spent now about 10hours at that error, trying to solve.
Hope u can help me
Thank u

If u need more information, please write it

**This is the whole error message**

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ((), {'email': 'admin@adminator.ch', 'first_name': 'ksfd', 'last_name': 'dfsg', 'location': 'Bern', 'date_of_birth': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'plz': 4589, 'license_plate_number': 80291, 'license_plate_char': 'BE', 'country': 'CH', 'address': 'adminstrasse', 'phone_number': '0453268', 'raw_password': 'Balmistar45!', 'is_staff': False, 'is_superuser': False}).
[08/Oct/2020 09:03:08] "POST /accounts/signup HTTP/1.1" 500 176373
```

**This is my model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def get_by_natural_key(self, email):
        return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: email})


country_choices = [
    ("CH", "CH"),
    ("DE", "DE"),
    ("FR", "FR"),
    ("BE", "BE"),
]


class UserLogin(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    replaces auth_user table
    examples for the fields:
    location : Bern, Biel
    license_plate_char : BE, NE, SG
    """

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    plz = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=country_choices)
    license_plate_char = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    license_plate_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from parking_mgmt.forms import UserForm
from django.contrib import auth

from parking_mgmt.models import UserLogin


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


"""Login"""


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')


def sign_up(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = UserLogin.objects.create_user(
                first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                location=form.cleaned_data['location'],
                date_of_birth=form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
                plz=form.cleaned_data['plz'],
                license_plate_number=form.cleaned_data['license_plate_number'],
                license_plate_char=form.cleaned_data['license_plate_char'],
                country=form.cleaned_data['country'],
                address=form.cleaned_data['address'],
                phone_number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                raw_password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            )
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'registration/logout.html')
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import UserLogin, ParkingLot, Reservation, Price


class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLogin
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "last_name", "location", "password1", "date_of_birth",
                  "plz", "license_plate_number", "license_plate_char", "country", "address", "phone_number")
```

**This is the traceback.**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 08, 2020 - 09:02:23
Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'djangoProject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Oct/2020 09:02:25] "GET /accounts/signup HTTP/1.1" 200 8372
[08/Oct/2020 09:02:25] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 160308
[08/Oct/2020 09:02:25] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 60050
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Oct/2020 09:02:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1827
Internal Server Error: /accounts/signup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\djangoProject\views.py", line 32, in sign_up
    user = UserLogin.objects.create_user(
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\parking_mgmt\models.py", line 26, in create_user
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\parking_mgmt\models.py", line 20, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 71, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 872, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "G:\BIS19\ÜK307 - HTML, CSS - Interaktive Webseite erstellen\Django Projekt\mod-307-bis19p\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ((), {'email': 'admin@adminator.ch', 'first_name': 'ksfd', 'last_name': 'dfsg', 'location': 'Bern', 'date_of_birth': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'plz': 4589, 'license_plate_number': 80291, 'license_plate_char': 'BE', 'country': 'CH', 'address': 'adminstrasse', 'phone_number': '0453268', 'raw_password': 'Balmistar45!', 'is_staff': False, 'is_superuser': False}).
[08/Oct/2020 09:03:08] "POST /accounts/signup HTTP/1.1" 500 176373

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hello, you might have some messed up migrations. If the data is not important to you, you can delete it: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html
I had the exact same error because of migrations error while using a custom model.

Comment: hmm yeah i already tried that, but i found the error

Comment: nope it came back :(   in views.py the   user = UserLogin.objects.create_user( goes to my models. but activates the wrong create_user function, so i changed it and then it worked, then the next error came, bout a password i fixed that too and now the same error occurs like the name of the thread :(

Comment: Ok, I'm going to insist on that because I had the exact same error. Erase your database, clear all your migrations, and do them again. Let me know if that works.

Comment: hmm i did that, still nothing.. but i think there is something wrong , cause my teacher merged it and tried it by himself and the sign up worked by him so, thats all that matters. its just a feature branch so, the other can use it and it works for them. Thank u very much for ur help sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just wanna write the Solution to the Problem.
Or just the thing that helped me.

Like @Charles said, it was just a migration error,
and something with my project was wrong too.
The Code worked perfectly, when my friend cloned the repo and tried it out.

So i just deleted the project on my computer.
Made a new Project and merged it down from my GitHub Repo and it worked.

So I hope I could help somebody with this.